# Struggling to understand how this multi-layer for loop works

Tags: javascript, loops

**Question**

The following function is supposed to create a two-dimensional array with m rows and n columns of zeroes.

**Answer**

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

**My Question**

I am familiar with having a for loop inside of a for loop, to iterate through a second layer of an array. But in this example it seems particularly confusing.

Please could you explain step by step what is happening here.

Comment: I guess the inline comments are self explanatory.

Comment: Sure, perhaps I am looking for a more detailed step by step e.g. rather than: Adds the m-th row into newArray - it loops through all of the m, and then moves onto the j. Maybe the question is stupid, I'm just struggling with it

Comment: I think this algorithm is _very_ confusing, and nonsense. The same reference row is mutated and pushed several times into the matrix. At the end, it shouldn't give a m * n matrix at all (proof : the snippet shows it, it gives a row of m * n zeros repeated m times). EDIT:  and I agree with Ashish Ranjan suggestion : do it on paper yourself, this is always enlightening

Comment: A better way to understand the code would be to do each step with pen/paper, have diagrams for `newArray`, `row` etc, and as they push 0's to it, or push `row` into `newArray`, you also push in your book. This should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't work, actually. If you run it you'll see it makes an array of 3x6 instead of 6x3.

Try this

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    let row = [];

    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

You need to re-init the row after pushing it, or, even better

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes
  let newArray = [];
    let row = [];
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
    }
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Don't re-do the work of initializing the row since all rows are the same